# generic delete does not work?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have this abstract repository class with a Delete method:

```
   public abstract class MyRepository<C, T> :
        IMyRepository<T>
        where T : class
        where C : ObjectContext, new()
    {
        private C _entities = new C();

        public C Context
        {
            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Attach(entity);
            _entities.DeleteObject(entity);
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

however this does not compile? how can I Create a generic delete method here?

Comment: Maybe `where T: object` instead of `where T: class`?

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.Attach(System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: and : Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey'

Comment: So, `where T : IEntityWithKey` then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
private C _entities = new C();
```

Use *Activator.CreateInstance*:

```
private C _entities = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `Delete` method as follows

```
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _entities.CreateObjectSet<T>().Attach(entity);
        _entities.DeleteObject(entity);
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        _entities.CreateObjectSet<T>().Attach(entity);
        _entities.ObjectStateManager
            .ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified); 
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: well something like this: _entities.CreateObjectSet<T>().Attach(entity);
            _entities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            _entities.SaveChanges();